# Which method of export for Testflight?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the problem that push notifications do not get delivered with an app I am testing with external testers via Testflight. Several posts point into the provisoning profile / certificate direction, which need to be set to the distribution ones.

I am using xCodes automatic signing, and when archiving and exporting, which option am I supposed to chose for exporting it for testlight?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First option will do. And make sure you're sending Push Notifications with correct certificates. Debug Mode and Release Mode should be handled separately. Sending Push Notifications to testflight/store build will need Production Certificates, and use Development Certificates otherwise.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! In Firebase (I am using their Cloud Messaging) I provided certificates for both.

Comment: Then provide correct certificates for both. It works like a charm.

Comment: they are correct I believe. Is there a difference code wise in the appdelegate?

Comment: Yes, you have to configure Firebase (setting APNS token) accordingly in AppDelegate. How are you configuring it?

Comment: You found it. `InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)` should be  `InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)`. Thanks!

Comment: Just pushed a new Build to testflight. Still not working. Do you know if the Firebase App Delegate Proxy needs to be set to true? Can't find docs on that. Sort of hard to debug where the notification is stuck.

Comment: Firebase app delegate proxy should be set to NO in info.plist.
If set to YES, it will swizzle the Push Notifications method. It isn't necessary for notifications to work.

Comment: Update: Works now. Everybody with similar problems really needs to check that everything is set to production instead of sandbox/development.